# How to call font from the directory where the source tex file exists?

Tags: fonts, polyglossia

I would like to use ``Akaash" Bengali font in my latex  article. But the font is nor installed in my system. I would like to call it(without installing) from the directory where the source file exists. How can I do this?

**MWE:**.

```
\documentclass[preview, margin=0.5cm]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{bengali}
% Replace this with whatever font you're using
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{Akaash}
\title{\textbengali{ইংরেজি} and Bengali}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

First English, \textbengali{তারপর বাংলা}
\end{document}
```

This provides errors:

```
fontspec error: "font-not-found" The font "Akaash" cannot be found.   
For immediate help type H <return>. ...tfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{Akaash}
```

Comment: use the filename (not the internal font name) and it should work `akash.otf` or whatever it is

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have used the name of file "AkaashNormal.ttf", but still errors occurred.

Comment: that's odd. luatex or xetex?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you very much my problem is solved with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Use the filename (not the internal font name) and it should work, so `AkaashNormal.ttf` or whatever the filename is.

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically need a version from the current directory to override a system font, you can add the `[Path=./]` option to `\newfontfamily`.